# Unable to add namespaces to lightning component markup using MavensMate

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mavensmate, namespace

I have enabled a namespace in my org, and am attempting to add markup to lightning components per the [Namespace Usage Examples and Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm) documentation. The component saves successfully in MavensMate/Sublime, however if I refresh from server, or view the component in Developer Console, I see that the namespace that I just added is missing.

**Steps to reproduce:**

In an org with a set namespace prefix, create a lightning component and an apex class.

Using MavensMate(v0.0.11) and Sublime (Build 3126) edit the first line of a lightning component as follows:

*Before:*

```
<aura:component controller="MyController">
```

*After:*

```
<aura:component controller="MyNamespace.MyController">
```

Save and observe that you receive a "successful" message.

Open the component in the Developer Console

*Expected:*

```
<aura:component controller="MyNamespace.MyController">
```

*Actual:*

```
<aura:component controller="MyController">
```

This also happens when attempting to add a namespace prefix to a component tag such as `<c:myComponent/>` -> `<MyNamespace:myComponent/>` or static resource references such as `{!$Resource.resourceName}` -> `{!$Resource.MyNamespace__resourceName}`

Comment: What if you add it via the dev console do u get same result. May be a tooling API issue

Comment: @Eric no, I am not able to reproduce this issue via the dev console.

Comment: Ok. I have had issues with ide before and thought it was ide then found out it was tooling API. You did check use tooling API when u tested dev console right?